# Integrating Automated Paypal shop system?

Tags: php, paypal

Hey guys for my website I am trying to figure out how to make an automated paypal shop, what I mean by that is when they purchase membership via paypal by clicking a paypal button on my website it will also change a value inside of my database for that specific user.

So in a timeline fashion:

1. User clicks buy button and purchases item.
2. After payment is complete, redirect to my php script which updates the users membership status.

Currently All I need help on is how to make it automatically redirect after the payment is complete. I followed some code but it still didn't work, here is what I'm using.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 

 <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. --> 
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MY EMAIL"> 

 <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. --> 
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 

 <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. --> 
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="MY URL TO REDIRECT TO">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sponsored (1 Month)"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">  
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="NZD"> 

 <!-- Display the payment button. --> 
 <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" 
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
 alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online"> 
 <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" 
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" > 
</form>
```

That code leaves you at the Paypal "payment complete" page, but I want it to automatically go to the return url on payment complete.

Comment: For some reason the code won't show up in the OP and I also cannot edit it for some reason, no changes are made.. So here is a pastebin link to the code: http://pastebin.com/ywWZGGpn

Comment: Your have to mark your code as code, read the help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I Did mark it is code, but I think something went wrong during that.

Answer (score 1):

that's not how paypal works, you can't rely on the visitors return, you use the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) feature of paypal, read its docs on how this works.

[Instant Payment Notification - PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)

Answer (score 0):

Is your return url really "MY URL TO REDIRECT TO" or is it something like "http://myURL.com/myPage.asp"? The first one wouldn't work, obviously.